# Serverless computing marketplace?

Tags: serverless-framework

I am looking for a place to buy/sell AWS lambda/azure functions/google functions scripts. Does anyone know if such a thing exists? Would anyone else be willing to pay for this?

Comment: At least for Azure https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/sell